# Oracle query to find unique occurrences of a column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my table:

```
ID|2ndID|Value
1|ABC|103
2|ABC|102
3|DEF|103
4|XYZ|105
```

My query should return all instance of the ID that has only one Value=103 for the 2ndID. It shouldn't return Ids 1 and 2 because apart from 103, ABC has 102 too. 3|DEF on the other hand has only one Value = 103. And I need such rows back. I don't need the 4|XYZ also since value <> 103. Based on the above sample set my result should only be.

```
3|DEF|103
```

I can use a group by 2ndID having COUNT(*) =1 which will return all but I don't know how to filter it only to Value = 103.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also have a fifth row with ID = 5, 2ndID = 'DEF', and value = 103? In that case, what is the desired result? Would you want to select that row also?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return all the row with a single 2ndId value

```
select * from 
my_table where 2ndId in (

select 2ndId 
from my_table  
group by 2ndId
having count(*)  =1 
)
```

And if you need  to enforce the filter for value 103

```
select * from 
my_table where 2ndId in (

select 2ndId 
from my_table  
group by 2ndId
having count(*)  =1 
)
and value = 103
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard application of the `HAVING` clause in aggregate queries. You want to group by the second id, and select only the groups that have only one row and where the min(value) is 103. `MIN(value)` will be the unique value in the unique row, in the groups that only have one row to begin with; and you don't care about any other groups.

**COMMENT**: This solution assumes that the combination `(second_id, value)` is unique - it can't appear in the table more than once, for different id's. I asked the OP in a Comment under the original question to clarify whether this is in fact the case.

```
with
  mytable ( id, second_id, value ) as (
    select 1, 'ABC', 103 from dual union all
    select 2, 'ABC', 102 from dual union all
    select 3, 'DEF', 103 from dual union all
    select 4, 'XYZ', 105 from dual
  )
-- End of SIMULATED inputs (for testing only, NOT PART OF THE SOLUTION).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select   min(id) as id, second_id, min(value) as value
from     mytable
group by second_id
having   count(*) = 1 and min(value) = 103
;

ID  SECOND_ID  VALUE
--  ---------  -----
 3  DEF          103
```